# MySQL DELETE statement with a join, HAVING and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table of items and another of reports. Each report has a foreign key linking to an item being reported.

I am trying to delete all items displayed in this query:

```
SELECT items.id, title, SUM(weight) AS total_weight, SUM(weight)*10/views AS score 
FROM items, reports 
WHERE items.id = reports.item_id 
GROUP BY items.id 
HAVING score >= 50;
```

Trying something like this:

```
DELETE items 
FROM (SELECT items.id, title, SUM(weight) AS total_weight, SUM(weight)*10/views AS score 
    FROM items, reports 
    WHERE items.id = reports.item_id 
    GROUP BY items.id 
    HAVING score >= 50)
AS T;
```

Gives me this error message:

```
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'items' in MULTI DELETE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you have to be careful about the subqueries.  I think the following works:

```
DELETE FROM items 
WHERE id IN (select *
             from (SELECT items.id 
                   FROM items join reports 
                        on items.id = reports.item_id 
                   GROUP BY items.id 
                   HAVING SUM(weight)*10/views >= 50
                  )
            )
```

It tricks the compiler into accepting the query by using an additional subquery.  I also fixed your `join` syntax.

The following, though, rewrites the query into a more common syntax, using a correlated subquery:

```
delete from items
where exists (select r.item_id
              from reports r
              where r.item_id = items.item_id 
              group by r.item_id
              having SUM(r.weight)*10/items.views >= 50
             )
```

This is guessing that `weight` and `views` come from `reports.  Otherwise, you need to put the`items` alias in front instead.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. The weights comes reports but views are with the items. What do you mean put the items alias infront?

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Very informative answer but din't execute for some reason. @var___'s answer worked for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM items 
WHERE 
  id IN (
    SELECT 
      items.id 
    FROM items, reports 
    WHERE items.id = reports.item_id 
    GROUP BY items.id 
    HAVING SUM(weight)*10/views >= 50)
```

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, I got this error: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Apparently MySQL doesn't accept this. Please try the answer by Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 2):

I believe  your `delete` statement is wrong. It should be `delete from tablename where [condition]`.

```
    DELETE FROM items 
    WHERE 
      id IN (
        Select T.id from (SELECT items.id, title, SUM(weight) AS total_weight, SUM(weight)*10/views AS score 
FROM items, reports 
WHERE items.id = reports.item_id 
GROUP BY items.id 
HAVING score >= 50) T)
```

Comment: Hmmm... Tried that too but I get this error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT items.id, title, SUM(weight) AS total_weight, SUM(weight)*10/views AS sc' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM items 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM (SELECT i.id itemId, (SUM(weight) * 10 / views) score
                   FROM items i INNER JOIN reports r ON i.id = r.item_id 
                   GROUP BY itemId HAVING score >= 50
                  ) AS A
            );
```

Comment: Thanks Saharsh. The answer by var___ worked well. With yours, I get the error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'items.id' in 'group statement'

Comment: I go an error saying: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'views' in 'having clause'